# Handling closeEvent accept/ignore

Tags: python, qt, event-handling, pyqt, pyside

I have a main window which pops a second window with some user options, the user can either click one of the options or close this new windows.

I want every time the user closes the windows to pop it again, and only close it when he selects a option.

I'm doing this:

```
class PopUp_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.accept_button.clicked.connect(lambda: 
                                       self.closeEvent(event=QCloseEvent, accepted=True))

    def closeEvent(self, event, accepted=False):
        if not accepted:
            self.parent.recreate_window()
            event.ignore()
        else:
            event.accept()
```

The windows is beign recreat if the user closes it, but it doesn't closes when he clicks the accept button.

Comment: Also, depending on what you are trying to achieve a wizard might help you. It has an `isComplete` method which can evaluate whether or not the user is allowed to close the wizard (based on some inputs, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `accepted` is always `False` then. And why are you reopening the pop up? If you ignore the event it will never close in the first place.

Do you need the lambda function? If not, something like this seems simpler:

```
class PopUp_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.accepted = False
        self.accept_button.clicked.connect(self.on_accept)

    def on_accept(self):
        self.accepted = True
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.accepted:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```